# Correct way to use SweetAlert2

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to use SweetAlert2, but I don't understand the right way to do so.

This is the link where I found the sweetalert2.min.js:
https://sweetalert2.github.io

I'm importing the file like this in my connectedCallback

```
import AllJsFilesSweetAlert from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/AllJsFilesSweetAlert'

    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, AllJsFilesSweetAlert + '/sweetalert-master/sweetalert2.min.js')]).then(() => { console.log('Files loaded sweetalert2.min.js.'); }).catch(error => { console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error)); });
        var box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
        if(box1){
            box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }, false); 
        }
    }
```

and i'm using like this in my code inside of some method

```
Swal.fire(
'The Internet?',
'That thing is still around?',
'question'
);
```

but when i'm trying to use I receive this error:
[image]

someone already passed through this?

Answer (score 1):

Sweetalert2 attempts to make modifications to `document.body`, which is specifically forbidden by Locker Service/Lightning Web Security. Unfortunately, that means, as written, this library is incompatible with Salesforce. Here's a [demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/7rMZ8T1hVw3h5VWaidZ9/src/app.css?p=stories) of SweetAlert2 working in LWC:

```
<template>
    <lightning-button onclick={handleClick} label="Click me!"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import swal from 'sweetalert2';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  handleClick() {
    new swal({title:'You did it!', text: 'You clicked the button successfully!' });
  }
}
```

---

You'd need to fork/clone the library and tweak it to make it compatible with Salesforce LWC.

Comment: hi sfdcfox, this means that the way of I'm import is wrong? Or means that you change the sweetalert2 file to use?

Comment: @MatheusCoelhoCampos I demonstrated a LWC OSS version that shows the library itself works, but not in Salesforce LWC. I will take a look this weekend and see if this is an easy fix to make it work in Salesforce or not.